# APIs from Next.js App work locally but produce errors when deployed to Netlify

Tags: javascript, next.js, deployment, netlify

The image attached shows the error I get when deploying my NextJS App APIs to Netlify. Locally, they all work well

[image: API NETLIFY ERROR]

Comment: The [mre] is `JSON.parse("Internal Server Error")`. You should probably look into: why the server is responding 500; and why the client is trying to parse the body as JSON anyway.

Comment: Please I don't understand what you mean by The minimal reproducible example is `JSON.parse("Internal Server Error")`

Answer (score 0):

On Netlify, I forgot to add the API key to my environment variable. Immediately after adding it, everything worked smoothly